# How to play sound through native extension in Air for Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, audio, air

I've noticed that sounds are terribly delayed in Air for Android.

Weird thing, but on some phones delay is unnoticeable (Samsung Galaxy Note 2, Galaxy S2), while on others (LG G2) it is bad! It's not just the first time playing sound is delayed (as I've seen others complain), but, for example, a sequence of repeated sound in sync with frames is delayed too - frames are finished, while the sounds still not finished playing (imagine a ball jumping 10 times fast (every jump produces a sound) and when the ball has jumped 10 times and stops, jump sound still plays 2-3 times).

It is terrible and unacceptable.

I've seen someone mention playing sounds through android native extension (.ane file), but no explanation how to do that.

So my question is - how do I write android native extension (or where can I find one) which simply plays sound without delay?

In Flash, I use this code to play sound:

var mySound:Sound = new librarySound();
mySound.play();

I have tried playing constant silence (silent sound), but it has it's flaws and I've rejected it.

I need simple sound play without delay. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this?: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html

Comment: I have seen and read this, but it doesn't do what i need (play sounds) and is too complicated for me to learn from and write my own native extension.